# Install lamp: 2 brown + 1 blue cable

Tags: lighting

I want to install a lamp with 4 cable, namly two brown, one blue and a yellow-green cable:

[image]

Out of my wall I found 4 cable (yellow-green, blue, brown and black):

[image]

I tried to connected the lamp as follows (Left side the lamp, right side my wall):

- blue-blue
- brown-brown
- brown-black

And

- blue-blue
- brown-black
- brown-brown

I didn't connect the yellow-green cable because I just wanted to check if the lamp works. However with both combinations, the light didn't go on. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Try with a multimetre (measure black-brown, black-blue and brown-blue) voltages. Blue should be the neutral "common", black and brown should be the live with one 'permanent live' and the other switched. PS: where are you? You have multiple switch controlling part of your fixture (es: one switch commanding a bulb and another controlling the other)?

Comment: Also, if possible post a pic of your your fixture with nuts 'far enough' to see the connections on each one

Comment: The single wires are called **wires**.  When a bunch of wires are together in a common jacket, that's a cable. There are no cables in your picture; those short clear things are more like sleeves.